# Erro ao Executar Classe de Teste

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Boa tarde! Tudo bem?

Ao executar a classe InformacoesUsuarioTest, a mesma está mostrando os seguintes erros:

- Error:(4, 20) java: package org.selenium does not exist
- Error:(5, 27) java: package org.selenium.chrome does not exist
- Error:(15, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class WebDriver
  location: class tests.InformacoesUsuarioTest
- Error:(15, 35) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ChromeDriver
  location: class tests.InformacoesUsuarioTest
  Também não estou conseguindo importar os pacotes da selenium.

**"InformacoesUsuarioTest.class"**

package tests;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class InformacoesUsuarioTest {

```
@Test
public void testAdicionarUmaInformacaoAdicionalDoUsuario( ) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Jéssica\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver navegador = new ChromeDriver(); //variavel navegador com uma instância chrome
    assertEquals(1,1);
}
```

}

O Arquivo **pom.xml** está configurado assim:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>br.com.juliodelima.webdriverjava</groupId>
<artifactId>webdriverJava</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Tentei refazer a configuração, porém, os erros persistem.

Vocês podem me ajudar, por favor?

Obrigada!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jéssica,

Verifiquei nos jars do selenium que os nomes dos pacotes iniciam com `org.openqa.selenium`. Altere os seus imports para:

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
```

Comment: Funcionou. Obrigada!